# whats wrong in this coding?

Tags: excel, vba

Whats wrong in this coding ? it is working in single cell but not in multiple cells

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim marks As Integer, result As String
marks = range("B2:B7")
If marks >= 33 Then
result = "pass"
Else
result = "fail"
End If
range("C2:C7").Value = result
End Sub
```

Comment: Should `marks` be the sum of the cells?  Or are you checking to see if each cell is `>= 33` ?

Comment: range("B2:B7") doesn't return an integer, it returns a range.

Comment: I'm also confused on why you need VBA for this.  This can be easily done with a formula.  Put this in cell C2 and copy down: `=IF(B2>=33,"pass","fail")`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are trying to achieve this...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Set Rng = Range("B2:B7")
For Each Cell In Rng
    If Cell >= 33 Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "Pass"
    Else
        Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "Fail"
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: yes thanks @sktneer